# Lisp: How can i get hold of the created instance inside initialize-instance :around method

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clos

I want to create an (:around qualified) specializer of initialize-instance for a class X that will first call-next-method and then will call make-instance of another class, supplying it with the created instance of X. How can i get hold of the created instance inside initialize-instance :around method? (assuming of course after having called call-next-method so we are at the finilizing side of :around)

EDIT:
Class A has a bi-directional relationship with Class B through a slot in each one that keeps the id of the other, but class A requires id of class B, while the opposite is not required. So the flow i want is:

1. make-instance 'classA
2. inside initialize-instance :around classA I would have:

   i. make-instance classB and aquire id-of-B.

   ii call-next-method adding id-of-B

   iii set the corresponding id-of-A slot of classB point to our created classA instance (this is my original question reason)

Now I could do [i] in :before and [iii] in :after, but i cant:
Classes A and B are persistent classes through elephant and I want to wrap the whole flow in a transaction which I wouldnt like to span many methods.  For those familiar with elephant, I want to use ensure-transaction wrapper, and I dont want to use explicit begin and commit function calls in different points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instance is passed as the first argument of `initialize-instance`.

```
(defmethod initialize-instance :around ((created myclass) ...)
  ;; do something with created
  created)
```

Comment: Wait, how is it possible? Unless the 'created' symbol in your example is always bound to something that changes during the scope of the method. So what is it really bound to before call-next-method is called?

Comment: @Paralife `created` is bound to the newly created instance.  Prior to the call to `call-next-method`, that newly created instance will only have had default initialization applied to it along with initialization applied by upstream methods (if any).

Comment: The default initialization you mention is defined where? is it implementation dependent? is it the initforms of the defclass? (actually it is the only think that would make sense to me)

Comment: @Paralife As @Svante said in his response, the instance is in a pretty raw state in the context of an :AROUND method.  Unless there are upstream methods (or non-standard metaobjects), the instance has little more than its slots allocated.  In particular, the slots are still not initialized.  The initialization sequence is described in [CLtL](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node298.html).

Comment: @Wreach Wait, dont :around methods implicitly enclose :after methods in their body if call-next-method has been called? I Know I should go look in CLtL and I will do, but i insist for the sake of completeness of the question here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Paralife Yes, :AROUND methods enclose :AFTER methods.  My comments were directed to the state of the instance prior to calling CALL-NEXT-METHOD.  @Svante's observation is that if one is going to wait until after CALL-NEXT-METHOD to perform additional work, one may as well use an :AFTER method.  Of course, if one wants to perform work after the :AFTER methods themselves, then :AROUND is the right place.

Answer (score 4):

You would usually do that with an `:after` method, not an `:around` method.  Unless you fiddle around deeply in the guts of CLOS, it does not make much sense to do anything with an uninitialized instance.  The instance is supplied as the first argument of `initialize-instance`.

For a deeper treatment, look at the [CLHS, section 7.1](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/07_a.htm).